# How to determine whether my content has a instagram embed?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, youtube, instagram

The posts in my site has video(single) from anyone of the following embeds.

1. Youtube
2. Facebook
3. Instagram

My question is while fetching them on front end I want to findo out whether my content has an embed, if so which of the following is embedded. (**iframe presence checking is one (dirty)way still it own work for instagram**)

**PHPCODE:**

```
    $video_start = strpos($singlePost->post_content, "<iframe");//Get to the start of the iframe(video)
    $video_stop = strpos($singlePost->post_content, "</iframe>");//Get to the end of the iframe(video)
    $iframe_content = substr($singlePost->post_content, $video_start, $video_stop);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($iframe_content));
    $iframe_src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//iframe/@src)");
    $parsed_url = parse_url($iframe_src);
    $host = $parsed_url['host'];

    if(strpos($host, "youtube") !== false) { // If it is a youtube video append this
        $iframe_src = $iframe_src."?rel=0";// This option has to be appended of youtube URL's
        $related_social_icon = "youtube";
        $related_social_media = "youtube";
    }

<iframe class="<?php echo $iframe_class; ?>" src="<?php echo $iframe_src; ?>" style="background-size: cover;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Above code works fine for youtube, but does not work for instagram coz when inserting instagram comes as blockquote tags,but if you echo them it will be straight away become iframe tags due to the script in it.

Comment: Gentlemen, thanks for this negative present, please tell me what made my post deserved this present. I don't think there is an existing question on this.

Comment: Honestly the question is too narrow. There is no sign of effort or posted code of things you have tried. Those things are what stackoverflow is for.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like this:

```
add_filter('the_content', function($content) {
    $identifier = '<embed';
    if (strpos($content, $identifier) !== false) {
        // identifier found
        $content = '<h1>This page includes an embed</h1>'.$content;
    }
    return $content;
});
```

I'm not sure how your embeds look like, you are talking about iframes to. So you need to find some identifiers that you can check.

Your post probably got downvoted because it could have some more information?

Comment: I have used the same as what you did, I used Iframe instead. But when it comes to instagram, the content placed is a blockquote, but what received is a iframe, that is where I got stuck.